# Add listview adapter to layout of Fragment

Tags: android, android-layout, android-listview, android-fragments, fragment

I want to generate the content of my Listview dynamically but don't know how to do it in this case, because I have it in a Fragment and not in the main Activity. 
Here is the Code:

```
public class Contacts extends FragmentActivity implements ActionBar.TabListener {

SectionsPagerAdapter mSectionsPagerAdapter;

/**
 * The {@link ViewPager} that will host the section contents.
 */
ViewPager mViewPager;
ListView myListView; // Listview here
ListView listview;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    setContentView(R.layout.activity_contacts);

    // Set up the action bar.
    final ActionBar actionBar = getActionBar();
    actionBar.setNavigationMode(ActionBar.NAVIGATION_MODE_TABS);

    // Create the adapter that will return a fragment for each of the three
    // primary sections of the app.
    mSectionsPagerAdapter = new SectionsPagerAdapter(
            getSupportFragmentManager());

    // Set up the ViewPager with the sections adapter.
    mViewPager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.pager);
    mViewPager.setAdapter(mSectionsPagerAdapter);
    getActionBar().setDisplayShowTitleEnabled(false);
    getActionBar().setDisplayUseLogoEnabled(false);
    getActionBar().setDisplayShowHomeEnabled(false);
    // When swiping between different sections, select the corresponding
    // tab. We can also use ActionBar.Tab#select() to do this if we have
    // a reference to the Tab.
    mViewPager
            .setOnPageChangeListener(new ViewPager.SimpleOnPageChangeListener() {
                @Override
                public void onPageSelected(int position) {
                    actionBar.setSelectedNavigationItem(position);
                }
            });

    // For each of the sections in the app, add a tab to the action bar.
    for (int i = 0; i < mSectionsPagerAdapter.getCount(); i++) {
        // Create a tab with text corresponding to the page title defined by
        // the adapter. Also specify this Activity object, which implements
        // the TabListener interface, as the callback (listener) for when
        // this tab is selected.
        actionBar.addTab(actionBar.newTab()
                .setText(mSectionsPagerAdapter.getPageTitle(i))
                .setTabListener(this));
    }

}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.contacts, menu);
    return true;
}

@Override
public void onTabSelected(ActionBar.Tab tab,
        FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction) {
    // When the given tab is selected, switch to the corresponding page in
    // the ViewPager.
    mViewPager.setCurrentItem(tab.getPosition());
}

@Override
public void onTabUnselected(ActionBar.Tab tab,
        FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction) {
}

@Override
public void onTabReselected(ActionBar.Tab tab,
        FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction) {
}

/**
 * A {@link FragmentPagerAdapter} that returns a fragment corresponding to
 * one of the sections/tabs/pages.
 */
public class SectionsPagerAdapter extends FragmentPagerAdapter {

    public SectionsPagerAdapter(FragmentManager fm) {
        super(fm);
    }

    @Override
    public Fragment getItem(int position) {
        // getItem is called to instantiate the fragment for the given page.
        // Return a DummySectionFragment (defined as a static inner class
        // below) with the page number as its lone argument.
        Fragment fragment = new DummySectionFragment();
        Bundle args = new Bundle();
        args.putInt(DummySectionFragment.ARG_SECTION_NUMBER, position + 1);
        fragment.setArguments(args);
        return fragment;
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        // Show 3 total pages.
        return 3;
    }

    @Override
    public CharSequence getPageTitle(int position) {
        Locale l = Locale.getDefault();
        switch (position) {
        case 0:

            return getString(R.string.contacts).toUpperCase(l);
        case 1:
            return getString(R.string.title_section2).toUpperCase(l);
        case 2:
            return getString(R.string.title_section3).toUpperCase(l);
        }
        return null;
    }
}

private class StableArrayAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<String> {

    HashMap<String, Integer> mIdMap = new HashMap<String, Integer>();

    public StableArrayAdapter(Context context, int textViewResourceId,
            List<String> objects) {
        super(context, textViewResourceId, objects);
        for (int i = 0; i < objects.size(); ++i) {
            mIdMap.put(objects.get(i), i);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int position) {
        String item = getItem(position);
        return mIdMap.get(item);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean hasStableIds() {
        return true;
    }

}

}
```

And the Fragment:

```
public class DummySectionFragment extends Fragment {
/**
 * The fragment argument representing the section number for this fragment.
 */
public static final String ARG_SECTION_NUMBER = "section_number";

public DummySectionFragment() {
}

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
        Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_contacts_dummy,
            container, false);
    if (getArguments().getInt(ARG_SECTION_NUMBER) == 2) {

        rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.contact_section, container,
                false);
        ListView listView1 = (ListView) rootView
                .findViewById(R.id.listview);

    } else {
        TextView dummyTextView = (TextView) rootView
                .findViewById(R.id.section_label);
        dummyTextView.setText(Integer.toString(getArguments().getInt(
                ARG_SECTION_NUMBER)));
        String[] values = new String[] { "Android", "iPhone",
                "WindowsMobile", "Blackberry", "WebOS", "Ubuntu",
                "Windows7", "Max OS X", "Linux", "OS/2", "Ubuntu",
                "Windows7", "Max OS X", "Linux", "OS/2", "Ubuntu",
                "Windows7", "Max OS X", "Linux", "OS/2", "Android",
                "iPhone", "WindowsMobile" };

        final ArrayList<String> list = new ArrayList<String>();
        for (int i = 0; i < values.length; ++i) {
            list.add(values[i]);
        }
        ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>     (this,R.id.listview);
    }

    return rootView;
}
}
```

Below are the Layout Files:

```
<android.support.v4.view.ViewPager xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:id="@+id/pager"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
tools:context=".Contacts" />
```

Second Layout:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
tools:context=".Contacts$DummySectionFragment" >

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/section_label"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

<ListView

    android:id="@+id/listview"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
```

Comment: You should use ListFragment instead of Fragment, also if you want to use add elements dynamically to an Activity, that Activity should be ListActivity instead

Comment: Thanks a lot. Could you give me an example I couldn't get it working.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It' s not that hard. Listactivity or activity, fragment or listfragment are both ok. Maybe the list* would have less code.

In your activty or fragment, setup the adapter, say, you use a ArrayAdapter. If your list has  a remove option, you need to use `LinkedList` to suppy elements, or you should use `ArrayList` for append option. and the set the adapter to the listview.

Every time the new elements coming or deleted, call the list(LinkedList or Arraylist) `add` or `remove`, and then call the adapter' s `notifyDataSetChanged` method.

I supose you forget to add your list(LinkedList or Arraylist) to the ArrayAdapter' s Construtor, like this, `new ArrayAdapter<String>(..., ..., ..., List<?>...)`

that' s it, please hava a try!